# How do I get mutiple files like html, css, javascript, and php in static

Tags: php, html, css, go, goland

As I said the title, How do I get mutiple files like html, css, javascript, and php in static using main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func formHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "ParseForm() err: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "POST request successful")
    name := r.FormValue("name")
    address := r.FormValue("address")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Name = %s\n", name)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Address = %s\n", address)
}

func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.URL.Path != "/hello" {
        http.Error(w, "404 not found", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    if r.Method != "GET" {
        http.Error(w, "method is not supported", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello!")
}

func main() {
    fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
    http.Handle("/static", fileServer)
    http.HandleFunc("/form", formHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", helloHandler)

    fmt.Printf("Starting server at port 8080\n")
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

also there are multiple files like this

[image]

but page shows wrong style, does anyone how to get these multiple files?

[image]

or how do i fix this?
fileServer := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))

Comment: If you want to serve the individual files that are rooted in `./static/` then the pattern in Handle should end with a slash, i.e. `http.Handle("/static/", fileServer)`, and you should also add [`http.StripPrefix`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.17.8#StripPrefix) (see the examples in the documentation for "how to").

Comment: And you rather do not want to statically serve .php files, what is the use case?

Comment: After taking php files from wordpress theme including css or javascript files too, the design of the website does not work on golang(go build and go run main.go).... how could I make a web site using golag... i seriously have no idea...please help me